# Возведение больших чисел в степень

Tags: c++, biginteger

Задача состоит в том, чтобы возвести большое число n ( 0 <= n <= 10^50) в степень m ( 0 < m < 1000). Для этого, безусловно, использую длинную арифметику

```
typedef vector<long long> largen;
```

А также бинарное возведение в степень.

```
largen recbinpow(largen a, int n) {
    largen e;
    e.push_back(1);
    if (n == 0)
        return e;
    if (n % 2 == 1)
        return multiply(recbinpow(a, n - 1), a);
    else {
        largen b = recbinpow(a, n / 2);
        return multiply(b, b);
    }
}
```

Но это всё равно оказалось слишком медленно. Я выяснил, что если брать основание системы счисления побольше, например 10^9, то возведение в степень будет происходить гораздо быстрее.

```
const int base = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

largen  multiply(largen a, largen b) {
    largen c(a.size() + b.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i<a.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0, carry = 0; j < (int)b.size() || carry; ++j) {
            long long cur = c[i + j] + a[i] * 1ll *(j < (int)b.size() ? b[j] : 0) + carry;
            carry = (long long)(cur / base);
            c[i + j] = (long long)(cur % base);
        }
    while (c.size() > 1 && c.back() == 0)
        c.pop_back();
    return c;
}
```

Но, по непонятным мне причинам, программа работает некорректно на некоторых значениях, например 999 999 999.

Часы отладки ни к чему не привели. Помогите, пожалуйста, отыскать ошибку [programme](http://cpp.sh/6vvcy).

Comment: Если есть написанный алгоритм дискретного преобразования Фурье и свертки, то умножение можно написать почти без пердолинга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы не хотите учесть, что ваш вывод

```
for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << result[i];
}
```

должен, вообще-то, выводить еще и ведущие нули (буде таковые имеются)?... Т.е. если ваш элемент вектора меньше того самого миллиарда, то он-то все равно должен выводиться в 9 знакомест?

Comment: Ведущие нули удаляются после каждого умножения. С выводом всё в порядке.

Comment: @KeltarHelviett Я просто в вашей программе ввел 100 и возвел в 20 степень. получил 1 с 8 нулями. Но если ваш вывод переписать вот так: `cout << setw(9) << setfill('0') << result[i];` - то получается единица с 40 нулями, как и надо... Так что с выводом у вас точно не все в порядке? это вы погорячились, утверждая, что все OK...

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Действительно, нужно было просто дополнять нулями, если число в векторе не состоит из 9 разрядов. Спасибо большое.